# Python package function for Jaccard Similarity between sets?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, set, multilabel-classification

Can one use scikit-learn (or another well-known python package) to get the Jaccard Similarity between a pair of *sets?*

I am only seeing the sklearn [`jaccard_similarity_score` function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score.html#sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score) working on vectors/arrays/tensors of equal length, whereas I really do need the [intersection-over-union](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jaccard_index) calculation, which is a set calculation, not a computation over two same-sized tensors.

Maybe I should be using [the multi-label-binarizer, exemplified here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117811/38146), if that's the intended way afforded by the scikit api.

Of course, it's few lines of code to implement myself with no package...

[image]
**this question is not a homework assignment, the slide I made for a non-technical audience at one time, and it illustrates the point here.*

Just wondering.

Comment: What sort of sets are the input? Which native Python or scipy/numpy object are they? Please show us a little code with reproducible data (random is fine).

Comment: How about sets in python? `len(intsersect) / len(union)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy has some [Set Routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.set.html) built in. In this case as @Harpal pointed out you could use the intersect and union operations.

In pure python using [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#frozenset.intersection) and [`union`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#frozenset.union):

```
gold = ['A', 'B', 'C']
clf = ['A', 'D']
gold_s = set(gold)
clf_s = set(clf)
jac_sim = len(gold_s.intersection(clf_s)) / len(gold_s.union(clf_s))
jac_sim
0.25
```

In NumPy using [`intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html#numpy.intersect1d) and [`union1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html#numpy.union1d) :

```
gold = np.array(gold)
clf = np.array(clf)
jac_sim = np.intersect1d(gold, clf).size / np.union1d(gold, clf).size
jac_sim
0.25
```

Granted the NumPy implementation is a good bit slower, but if your data is already in a NumPy array it may be faster than converting it to a set and doing the computation in Python. It all depends on the size of your data.

Comment: This answer is awesome. I am just left wondering whether NumPy really doesn't have built-in support for Jaccard similarity, and other simple measures. I guess being applicable to only vectors, it was not that interesting to add such simple things to NumPy.